# How to write a basic assembler in C?

Tags: c, assembly, od

So im attempting to write a basic Assembler in C that will take in two files, one input and one output. The Input will contain the instruction and the output will contain the assembled code which can be seen using "od -x output.txt | head -5" for example. My question however is how can this be done for a branching instruction? Provided below is the add instruction which also produces a weird output i dont quite understand either, in hand assembly for "add R2 R4 R1" it should produce an output of "1241" but instead it produces an output of "4112". Why does it do this?

**PR1.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ltrim(char *s) {
    while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') s++;
    return s;
}

char getRegister(char *text) {
    if (*text == 'r' || *text=='R') text++;
    return atoi(text);
}

int assembleLine(char *text, unsigned char* bytes) {
    text = ltrim(text);
    char *keyWord = strtok(text," ");
    if (strcmp("add",keyWord) == 0) {
        bytes[0] = 0x10;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL," "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL," ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL," "));
        return 2;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *src = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE *dst = fopen(argv[2],"w");
    while (!feof(src)) {
        unsigned char bytes[4];
        char line[1000];
        if (NULL != fgets(line, 1000, src)) {
            printf ("read: %s\n",line);
            int byteCount = assembleLine(line,bytes);
            fwrite(bytes,byteCount,1,dst);
        }
    }
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. if you want to support forward jumps with labels you can't output synchronously with input 2. that's just misuse of `od`. You asked for `-x` which is _"select hexadecimal 2-byte units"_ according to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html). You want `od -t x1` to see single byte units instead.

Comment: At the moment im not concerned fully with executing the instructions but rather just reading them and translating them into an output file. In essence i just want to read a line from the input.txt, split it into words, use the first word to determine the opcode and then use that opcode to process the rest of the line and output either 2 or 4 bytes depending on the input word. But im still confused with why that differing hexadecimal output is produced.

Comment: I never said anything about executing instructions. I only told you you can't encode a branch offset forward to a yet unseen label.

Comment: Ah i misunderstood then. Can i not do this though without a label and simply based on a predetermined offset as awful as that may sound in practice. Such as "Branchifless R1 R2 20"

Comment: Yes that would work, but that of course forces your input to know the offset to the branch target. Since your architecture seems to use variable length (at least 2 or 4 bytes) that's not a trivial matter such as counting lines.

Comment: Awesome, thats how i am to do this then. But why does the output.txt still produce that odd hexidecimal output? If im not mistaken when hand assembling the add instruction for "add R2 R4 R1" It would be 1241 but here im getting an output of "4122" ?

Comment: Told you why. You used `od` wrong. Alternatively to `-t x1` you can supply `--endian=big`

Comment: Now i understand. Thank you.

Comment: `hexdump -C` is a convenient command to remember.  (Or even `hd` if your distro installs that as an alias for it)